# URLClassLoader : How to set the URL

Tags: java, class, url, tomcat, urlclassloader

Suppose in  tomcat,It have two applications :app1 and app2,the folder structure is as below
tomcat6
   -webapps
      -app1
         -WEB-INF
             -lib
                -test1.jar
      -app2
          -WEB-INF
             -lib
                -test2.jar
Now in test1.jar,it have one class need to load the class in test2.jar,How to achieve this?i know in java,It have URLClassLoader which could load remote class,But how to set the URL?
Thanks

Comment: Why not copy have a copy of test2.jar in app1/WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,app1  is similar to a forwarder,It is common application,app2 is special business login handling app,we can't copy app2's jar to app1